# Server crash may leak php source code?

Tags: php, linux, nginx, fastcgi

I surfed a popular forum in my country ordinarily, but the connection is obviously much slower.

Later the server crashed, sometimes showing "Too many connections" error, sometimes the forum.php source code was downloaded.

Isn't PHP supposed to be execute on the server machine only? I dont understand how a server crash can leak the php source code. This is a very serious security problem, how should we prevent this?

Below are some information of the server:

System: Linux VM35 3.5.5-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Oct 4 15:44:44 EDT 2012 x86_64

Server API: CGI/FastCGI

Server: nginx/1.2.8

**Update:** The code has nothing sensitive so I am posting the php file here: [forum.php](http://pastebin.com/p4Siuuha)

Comment: PHP source code should never contain anything sensitive anyway ;) Config files for DB passwords, abstract away DB access itself, stuff like that.

Comment: Did you check the contents of forum.php? Was it definitely PHP source code or was it the generated HTML?

Comment: Yes, juts wanted to ask the same question :)

Comment: It is php source code although it does not contain any sensitive information. By the code, I can figure out the way to enter the debug mode. Anyway, even if the code does not contain anything sensitive, the admin will never wanted his source code being leaked

Comment: Do not instrument production code with debugging statements.

Comment: I had tried to host a php file which I can type password in the url to get some control of a remote machine. Until now, I can tell this is not safe

Comment: I took a look at the source. But it doesn't make any sense since there was nothing parsed within that file (at that moment). If there is a bug, it might be in some other file, loaded and parsed before this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you get a `Too many connections` error when you try to connect to the MySQL server, this means that `all available connections are in use by other clients.`

The number of connections permitted is controlled by the `max_connections` system variable. Beginning with MySQL 5.1. its `default value is 151` to improve performance when MySQL is used with the Apache Web server. Set a larger value for this variable if you need to support more connections.

But this shouldn't "crash" the whole server. The PHP code doesn't have a leak issue to face this situation.

In addition, if you got PHP source code instead of HTML generated by forum.php file, than you should check your web-server's log, having in mind the time when it happened 'cause at that time it stopped parsing PHP code.

However, whenever it's possible, an application should catch these errors, warnings and notices and show back to the users in more friendly manner.

Comment: Yes, I know about the connection error. I want to understand how a server crash can leak php source code

Comment: I wish I can check the server log to figure out the cause :(

Comment: I see, do you have a .htaccess within that folder, does it contain something like `application/x-httpd-php`, or `AddType ...` or any other suspicious code?

Comment: I dont host the forum. I just accidentally downloaded the source code

Comment: Do they have an award for the one who might hacked their site? :) You have a proof, show them ;)

Comment: It could be my first and the last award about hacking:)

Comment: You never know :) It may be a beginning of your hacking career :)

Comment: If your users are seeing "Too many connections" then there's horrible problems in the PHP config and the code your running as well as problems with the webserver.

Comment: @symcbean Well, that's not entirely true :) Let's say you limited `max_connection` to 1000 and you have a tiny script like `connect-to-mysql-> select-a-joke->show-it` And on the other side I fire 10000 requests towards your application. Is this mysql's or app's fault? What would you like to get from the server :)

Comment: But catching these errors and showing them to the users in more friendly fashion is a different topic.

Comment: Question was about security - and losing control over the information sent to the browser - leaking unhandled error messages *is* on topic.